# Can't boot Kali with UEFI Stuck at grub-rescue

Tags: kali-linux, system-installation, grub2, dual-boot, partition-table

I had Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop and just decided to try Kali. I downloaded Kali Linux 64 Bit and installed it using a live USB. Everything looked fine during the installation but I think I messed up something because I got stuck at `grub-rescue` getting this:

> Unknown btrfs filesystem
>
> Unknown filesystem

I tried to find the root partition and set prefix to it but the output of all
`ls (hd0,xxxx)` is

> Unknown filesystem

.

I tried this [fix](https://kali.training/forums/topic/how-to-repair-kali-linux-grub-in-pcs-with-uefi-firmware/) but in `update-grub` step I get this:

> WARNING: Device /dev/loop0 not initialized in udev database even after
>   waiting 10000000 microseconds.
>
> WARNING: Device /dev/sda1 not initialized in udev database even after
>   waiting 10000000 microseconds.
>
> ....
>
> done

and everything's still the same.

Here's `fdisk -l`  result:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LM024 HN-M
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7c12e647

Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          978942  315856895  314877954 150.1G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda2  *         2048     976895     974848   476M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda3       315856896  718577663  402720768   192G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       718577664 1953521663 1234944000 588.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5         4210688   88101312   83890625    40G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6        88102912  308043775  219940864 104.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       308045824  315856895    7811072   3.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda8          978944    4210687    3231744   1.6G 83 Linux
```

Comment: Welcome, This [answer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/353780/498780) explain why the installation fail. Because you are trying to install kali-linux in a dos partition table in UEFI mode. The easy way to install Ubuntu on legacy boot and Kali in UEFI is to convert the partition table to GPT. A backup using a live linux system is strongly recommended.